GWS-Admin dynamic filter with substring
I would like to create a dynamic filter in my Google Admin Console that contains all users from my Google domain who have the substring ‘stefan’ in their email address (e.g. Stefan.Meier, Hans-Stefan.Doe,....). The field to be searched in is: ‘user.primary_email’. My question now is what should the filter be if I want to filter by the substring?
Who has the solution for me or help where my error lies - I just can't get any further.
Thanks in advance

Unfortunately, the mode of searching available to Google Admin Console is limited as what is posted on the Find a User Account article. If you wish to do the advanced searches, you may be able to do it using Directory API (specific operators can be found in this article).
